# SSRS Show Base64 String or Byte Array From URL as Image

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a wevservice that returns an image as a Base64 string, or as a byte array, that I need to show as an image in SSRS. Not sure how to do that.

I tried using an expression in the image properties:

```
=System.Convert.FromBase64String("http://localhost:5460/api/Report/GetImage")
```

but that does not work. How do I get the string or array from the URL, then display it as an image?

I have also tried a Code block, but when I try

```
Dim hwr As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
hwr = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:5460/api/Report/GetImage")
```

I get the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: 
Insufficient permissions for setting the configuration property 'maximumErrorResponseLength'. (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\sql\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\ssrs\PreviewProcessingService.exe.Config line 42)     C:\Users\Desktop\REP90011\REP90011.rdl  0
```

This is on my local machine, not on the SSRS server or through IIS. Just through the preview pane in VS 2017.

Comment: I dont this will work. You will need to execute the webservice and store the return Base64 string in a variable and then pass the variable to the function. Did you tried manually passing a base64 string?

Comment: No this does not work. How do I get the string from the URL is what I'm asking?

Comment: You might want to look for how to consume a service in SSRS first in that case.

Comment: Yes, again, that is what I'm asking. How do I do that?

Comment: `Insufficient permissions for setting the configuration property 'maximumErrorResponseLength'` I see its showing this error. What is the image size? You can search for this error and you will find relevant threads with solutions.

Comment: Also check if your service can just return Base64 instead of image. That would make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I need to allow permissions in the file RSPreviewPolicy.config on my desktop to be 'FullTrust' instead of 'Nothing' in order to be able to use 'System.Net.WebRequest.Create'.

Edit:
I have been asked to expand on how my process works, so here it is:

I have a webservice that fetches an image and returns it as a base64 string.

Put an image object on the report, set it to 'Database', 'image/bmp', and use this expression as the field:

```
=Convert.FromBase64String(Code.GetImageString("http://localhost:5460/api/Report/GetImage")
```

The URL being the webservice that returns the string.

The function GetImageString is in the Code section of report properties:

```
Public Function GetImageString(Url As String) As String
   'create web request
   Dim hwr As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
   'this line is what I needed to change the permissions for
   hwr = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url) 
   hwr .Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
   'get response from request
   Dim wr As System.Net.WebResponse
   wr = hwr.GetResponse()
   'get stream from response
   Dim sr as System.IO.Stream
   sr = wr.GetResponseStream()
   'read response stream
   Dim read As IO.StreamReader
   read = new IO.StreamReader(sr, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
   'convert stream to string
   Dim result as string
   result = read.ReadToEnd
   return result.substring(1, result.length - 2) 'remove first and last characters, it's putting in quotes
 End Function
```

In VS 2017 this worked fine on my desktop. In VS 2019 it shows a red x on my desktop, but still works when deployed to the server.

Comment: So, you are saying if you use =System.Convert.FromBase64String("http://localhost:5460/api/Report/GetImage") as an external source for your image and the API returns Base64 string you can see the image? In published reports as well? Can you please help me to find RSPreviewPolicy.config file. Thanks I just checked my computer and could not find that file.

Comment: Not quite as simple as that. The expression for the image looks more like =Convert.FromBase64String(Code.GetImageString("localhost:5460/api/Report/GetImage") where the function GetImageString creates a web request to given URL, then converts the reponse stream to a string. I found RSPreviewPolicy.config on my PC here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS

Comment: Well, my backend already does conversion from Base64 into a byte array. Hre is my code: byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
            MemoryStream exportStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
            imageBytes.Length);
            exportStream.Position = 0;
            return Ok(exportStream); I see the image in the design pan, but when I run it it shows red x. My external source looks like this: http://localhost:5000/runNodeScript

Comment: What does GetImage return?

Comment: GetImage returns the image as a base 64 string. Since I upgraded from VS 2017 to VS 2019, all the images show as red x when run on my desktop. The image won't display properly until the report is deployed on the server. Still works fine in 2017 though.

Comment: For me it's not working in published reports. Can you please share your GetImageString function please?

Comment: @Mark see my expanded answer above.

Comment: Here is my external source: ="Code.GetImageString(http://localhost:5000/runNodeScript)" it does not hit the API. Also would it make any difference if I do Base64 conversion in the API itself?

Comment: You probably need to add "http://" to your URL. Copy/Paste error in my example. Or you're getting the same permissions error that made me to have to alter the config file. My API returns it as a base64, then it does it again in the SSRS report. Not sure if both are necessary, but the API is used by other services so it needs to be that way. It works though

Comment: I do have http:// in front of it. No, I am not getting any errors. It's just not hitting the API when I use your function.